# How can I access the output of my backup camera?

Tags: obd-ii

My 2016 Subaru Forester has a backup camera. First I've ever had, and very neat.  Of course, it engages the screen when I put the car in reverse, and shuts off in other gears.  I've been reading about the Media-oriented system transport, (MOST) network and understand that some, but hardly all, cars use this to carry high bandwidth data data like CD player and video. Are back-up cameras typically hardwired? Other questions suggest that. I'd like to capture the output of the camera at "arbitrary" times.  Assuming the the backup camera is wired to the MOST network (or some other) is there an accessible port available (such as the obd-ii port?)

As I was typing this, this question was suggested as related: [Is it possible to access multiple CAN buses through the OBD-II port?](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/26757/is-it-possible-to-access-multiple-can-buses-through-the-obd-ii-port)

Thanks!

Comment: OE cameras are hardwired, It may be over a data line on Subaru's you'd have to tap into the wiring with a scope to be sure though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is no such port. The camera sends video directly to its destination. Sometimes the video is analog. Sometimes the video is digitized.

Answer (score 2):

Reading from [the Wikipedia article of OBD](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/On-board_diagnostics), the various protocols supported have data rates from 1.2 kbit/s to 500 kbit/s. Most of the protocols have such low data rates that it is very clear video cannot be transmitted. In theory, the 500 kbit/s could be enough for very low quality digitally compressed video if using advanced compression technologies, but the low data rates of all of these protocols clearly demonstrate that the OBD connector is not a connector for transferring live video picture.

So, the answer to part of your question is: no, the OBD port won't help you in any way.

Comment: +1 OBD-II has appalling data refresh rate if you're polling multiple PID's; definitely not suited for streaming videos